# redirect with model object in spring

Tags: java, spring, jsp

i need to pass an object into a page that i'm going to redirect

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createNewQuest",method={ RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public ModelAndView createNewQuest(Quest quest,ModelAndView mav) {
        questService.addQuest(quest);


        mav.addObject("quest", quest);
        mav.setViewName("redirect:/control/displayQuest");
        return mav;
    }
```

my controller class seems like this but displayQuest page not getting the quest object?

any help wil be greatly appreciabl..

Comment: you looking for FlashAttribute [see](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html)

Comment: can you please put your redirect controller here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring added [Flash Attributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-flash-attributes) to handle this scenario:

> Annotated controllers typically do not need to work with FlashMap
>   directly. Instead an @RequestMapping method can accept an argument of
>   type RedirectAttributes and use it to add flash attributes for a
>   redirect scenario. Flash attributes added via RedirectAttributes are
>   automatically propagated to the "output" FlashMap. Similarly after the
>   redirect attributes from the "input" FlashMap are automatically added
>   to the Model of the controller serving the target URL.

**Example**

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/createNewQuest",method={ RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public ModelAndView createNewQuest(@ModelAttribute("quest") Quest quest,
         BindingResult binding, ModelAndView mav, 
             final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        questService.addQuest(quest);

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("quest", quest);
        mav.setViewName("redirect:/control/displayQuest");
        return mav;
    }
```

Comment: its showing HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvocationException: Failed to invoke handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.quest.controller.QuestController.createNewQuest(com.quest.model.dto.Quest,org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes)];

Comment: And it was working before?  I find it interesting that `@ModelAttribute` is not placed before `Quest`.

Comment: yes itz wornking before this, but not setting the object was theproblem

Comment: So `Quest` was not being databinded from some form?

Comment: how it get databinded?

Comment: You must use `ModelAttribute` and `BindingResult` in the controller to databind an object from some request data.

Comment: Then the `name` attributes or request parameters on your form must match up with the fields on the `Quest` object.  So if quest had a `year` field, you would need an input like `<input name="year"/>` and the `Quest` object would need getters/setters for year.  Assuming you are not using the Spring TagLib.

Comment: I'm slightly confused about where `Quest` was not being set.  Was it not being set in the method you provided or the method you redirected to (not seen)?

Comment: actually i need to get this quest object in displayQuest jsp page, so that i can use it...

Comment: Okay, but the redirect is going to go to a controller first, in that controller you need to add the `Quest` object as a parameter to the controller method.  Such as in the second controller method shown here: http://vard-lokkur.blogspot.com/2012/02/spring-mvc-flash-attributes.html

Answer (score 0):

if you are using spring form tag , then your form tag should look like below

```
<form:form name="yourformname" id="formid" commandName="quest">
```

then you controller model object "quest" will be mapped to spring form tag commandName variable, later you can access the variable